# Why is this compound primary key not working as expected?

Tags: mysql-error-1062, compound-key

I have a table "tbl_project_user_assignment" with a compound primary key.

It is made up of project_id and user_id

Each of these are also a foreign key to the project and user tables respectively.

At the moment, I have 2 entries in this table as below...

```
project_id | user_id
--------------------
1          | 1
1          | 2
```

When I run this sql query...

> INSERT INTO
>   tbl_project_user_assignment
>   (project_id, user_id) VALUES (2, 1);

...I get the following error message:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062
>   Duplicate entry '1' for key
>   'FK_project_user'

The FK_project_user key is the one linking the project_id to the tbl_project id.

This doesn't make sense to me because the values I'm inserting are unique...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code for creating the three tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `FK_project_user` is a unique key. Try dropping temporarily that constraint and perform the insert again.

If insert works, recreate the constraint making sure it's not flagged as `unique` anymore.

Comment: Thanks Pablo, That was spot on!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have:

- a foreign key relation to project
- a foreign key relation to user
- a unique constraint on (project, user)
- possibly a primary key on the combination of (project, user) OR a separate key field
  If you choose a combined PK you wouldn't need an extra constraint of course.

And it seems you have a unique constraint on user (by itself).

Posting the `show create table` statement would help even more.